# Calabash Android - Is there a way to input text without having to include the field?

Tags: gherkin, calabash-android

Is there a way that I can just enter text in my script by typing

```
Then I enter "fgood2@hotmail.com"
```

rather than

```
Then I enter "fgood2@hotmail.com" into "edit_text_dialog_first_field"?
```

This is for Calabash Android.

Thanks

Comment: Could you re-write the question, I can hardly understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, I re edited.  I just want to be able to enter text without having to include the field for the script in the .feature file.  When I just try to enter text alone, I will get an error message that the step is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write `.feature` file in anyway but you have to write `step definitions`according to your feature.

This `Then I enter "fgood2@hotmail.com` or  this `Then I enter "fgood2@hotmail.com" into "edit_text_dialog_first_field"?` does not matter.

**If you use**

```
Then I enter "fgood2@hotmail.com" into "edit_text_dialog_first_field"?
```

***Your Step Definition will  be***

```
Then (/^I enter "(.*?)" into "(.*?)$/") do | arg1, arg2 |
  do action...
end
```

**If you use**

```
Then I enter "fgood2@hotmail.com
```

***Your Step Definition will be***

```
Then (/^I enter "(.*?)") do | arg1 |
  do action...
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you create a custom step definition then you can call that step in your scenario. Using the predefined steps are generally poor practice.

- Create a folder called android_steps inside of you Features file
- Create a file in that folder called my_steps.rb (Eventually you would want multiple step files that are specific to one are aka landing page, sign in, menu)
- Using regex you can create a step definition inside of your my_steps.rb file
- It would look something like

  ```
  Then (/^I enter (.*)$/) do |information|
      touch("* id:'Field_id_you_want_to_enter_info_into'")
      keyboard_enter_text(information)
  end
  ```

I recommend you make a more intuitive step name though something along the lines of I enter the (.*) into the username field
I have started creating an intro guide on youtube. Please reference
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLInoIpH9dfLyvdaOjozON9QnQP1pK30y-

Comment: Using `enter_text(query,text)` is generally better than touching and entering text using primitive gestures yourself. Using enter_text tries to ensure that the text is actually entered into the targeted field as well as ensuing that it is appended.

Comment: I would recommend writing the step like "Then I enter a valid email" - assuming you are testing valid emails or trying to log in.

Answer (score 0):

Yeap, custom steps helps out much better, if you need some examples, try this link [here](http://docs.testmunk.com/en/latest/steps.html).